# Excel Drop Down Data Population Issue

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an excel workbook with a drop down that allows the user to select a region (west, central, east) and populates the associated addresses from my data sheet. My problem is that when central is selected all of the names populate correctly, but if either east or west are selected it only brings back the first name in the list on the data sheet. The vlookup is the same and shouldnt have this issue, can someone help me sort this out so that my names will populate correctly?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need a [reprex]. Maybe [edit] your question with a screenshot showing the problem.

Comment: Does this help BigBen?

Comment: It does. I would think you need absolute row references: `=VLOOKUP(C3, Data!A$21:B$198,2,False)`.

Comment: I thought that was the vlookup that I had in there. Either way it still does the came thing, Central will show correctly while the others all just show the first entry all the way down

Comment: `VLOOKUP` only returns the first match. It won't return successive matches. Maybe use a pivot table for this. "Central" was only "working" because you had relative references.

Comment: I was wondering if that would be a viable workaround. I will give it a shot! Thanks so much for the help!